Orthogonal Regression in Scipy vs Minitab
With orthogonal regression, I get a good result I expect using Scipy's ODR. When using Minitab, I get the same fit line coefficients, but different standard error of the coefficients. When I code the formulas provided on the minitab site, I reproduce the Minitab results. When I code the ODR equations, I reproduce them as well. The equations are different. Which one is right?
On the data
Xdata = [ 10.34784558, 10.94064173, 10.23649055, 10.45157219, 10.55453868, 10.53247146, 10.58184674, 10.45940627, 10.75889274,
          10.53971948, 10.45765687, 10.28922268, 10.44399545, 10.94139690, 10.14964179, 10.74251581, 10.90342996, 10.13820873]
Ydata = [ 10.78148621, 10.69600752, 10.37776633, 10.68787806, 10.60877923, 10.48270002, 10.14713767, 10.82750713, 10.90330951, 
          10.09866607, 10.72730271, 10.05368559, 10.21014499, 10.96834561, 10.66875493, 10.56152613, 10.94521825, 10.33797555 ]

ODR produces
Beta: [ 1.39804004 -4.15565265]
Beta Std Error: [0.43293193 4.5578139 ]
Beta Covariance: [[  4.58407532 -48.25235891]
 [-48.25235891 508.07249152]]
Residual Variance: 0.04088721168566028
Inverse Condition #: 0.00883261489134492
Reason(s) for Halting:
  Sum of squares convergence

Whereas minitab produces



Predictor
Coef
SE Coef
Z
P
Approx 95% CI




Constant
-4.15702
7.07917
-0.5872
0.557
(-18.0319, 9.71790)


X
1.39817
0.67249
2.0791
0.038
(0.0801, 2.71623)



Notice the standard errors are different, 0.432 vs 0.672 on X, and 4.58 vs 7.08 on the constant.  The ODR coefficients I can reproduce using the formulas in Mandel.  These formulas are different from those in the Minitab reference.
Any ideas on why the difference and which are 'better'?
